# sign_in_button.click() not working from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I can't find any solution for this. Can anyone suggest why from `selenium.webdriver.common.keys` import Keys is not working and clicking

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver.get("https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/search/?f_LF=f_AL&geoId=102257491&keywords=marketing%20intern&location=London%2C%20England%2C%20United%20Kingdom&redirect=false&position=1&pageNum=0")

sign_in_button = driver.find_elements(By.LINK_TEXT, "Sign in")
sign_in_button.click()

driver.quit()
```

Any other class to use for clicking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change `driver.find_elements` to `driver.find_element`.

Answer (score 0):

If you will not use `selenium.webdriver.common.keys` the `Keyboard` action in your code it will not work. I can't see in your code that you used `keyboard` action. However there is an issue in your code, `find_elements` will find the list not the `single` `element` that you are looking for, so,

Change the below line

***From***

```
sign_in_button = driver.find_elements(By.LINK_TEXT, "Sign in")
```

***To***

```
sign_in_button = driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, "Sign in")
```